# Cannot get Ant design Table cell to have reference to dynamic # of columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html-table, antd

I'm trying to get a cell on a Ant Design `<Table />` to have a reference to the dynamic definitions of the columns passed into the `<Table />` element. However, when I call the function it never has the updated values. I think its an issue with the scope but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Example of the issue, click `Add Column` and you will see the number of columns increase, then click on either button in the table. It calls a function set on the parent component that is passed a reference to the `columns` object, but it is the initial value of the `columns` not the current value. (output is in the console).

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-form-item-antd4169-forked-fsunr?file=/index.js

Code =>

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, Table } from "antd";
import { CustomCell } from "./custom-cell.component";

const dataSource = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "Click Me"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Or Me"
  }
];

const TableComponent = () => {
  const defaultColumns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      onCell: (record) => {
        return {
          record,
          testFunction: () => {
            console.log(`On test I have **${columns.length}** columns`);
          }
        };
      }
    }
  ];
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(defaultColumns);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Updated to have **${columns.length}** number of columns`);
  }, [columns]);

  const onClick = () => {
    const val = `Column ${columns.length + 1}`;
    setColumns([...columns, { title: val, dataIndex: val, key: val }]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={onClick}>Add column</Button>{" "}
      <Table
        dataSource={dataSource}
        columns={columns}
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: CustomCell
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<TableComponent />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Custom Cell

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";

export const CustomCell = ({ record, testFunction, children }) => {
  if (record?.name) {
    return <Button onClick={testFunction}>{record.name}</Button>;
  }
  return children;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and managed to achieve logging the correct number of columns on the button click for a cell:

Removed the `testFunction` from `onCell`, now it returns only `record`.

```
const defaultColumns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    onCell: (record) => ({ record }),
  },
];
```

Created a simple getColumns function that does what your testFunction used to do, this is implemented right under your useState.

```
const getColumns = () => {
  console.log(columns);
};
```

Edited your body > cell render function, so it now adds the `getColumns` function there, assigning it to `testFunction` prop, together with `record` and `children`, meaning your `testFunction` will always get the updated columns from the state.

```
<Table
  dataSource={dataSource}
  columns={columns}
  components={{
    body: {
      cell: ({ record, children }) => (
        <CustomCell
          record={record}
          testFunction={() => getColumns()}
          children={children}
        />
      ),
    },
  }}
/>;
```

If this works for you please let me know, otherwise please mention what didn't work, so I can update my answer (also comment if you need further clarification). I tested this on your code sandbox and it's working.